# Sharing Private keys in application development

Tags: java, private-key, pki, jks

How do large corporations manage to share Private keys? i.e. An application is in the building stage, there is one group of developers with a private key, this gives them access to develop the application. It is a large application, that requires to reach out to multiple groups of developers to help build on it. Please assist me in a way where I can get that same private key to the other groups, or is that not possible and each group would need a separate private key?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to share your private keys with your developers...you should restrict access to the private key to a very small group of trusted people.

To allow developers to work on code you can use Delay Signing/Test Key signing:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/03/17/91575.aspx

On your secured CI/Build Server that generates your "releases"...you would allow it access to the production private key and then use that in the build process during a "Release" build (which doesn't use Delay Signing) to sign everything properly.

- [What exactly are Delay signing and strong names in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394357/what-exactly-are-delay-signing-and-strong-names-in-net)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/10/24/484170.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/06/23/644648.aspx